# Retrieve contacts from Outlook Contact Group not Contact List using C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I need to retrieve the email addresses from a user specified Outlook 2013 Contact Group. This VBA code I found elsewhere works perfectly but I need to convert it to C#. All of the C# examples I’ve found pull the addresses from the Contact List instead of the user created Contact Group. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    Public Function GetContactGroupAddresses()
        Dim I As Integer
        Dim AddressList As String
        Dim Group As String
        Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim myNamespace As Object
        Dim myFolder As Object
        Dim myItem As Object
        Dim WordApp As Object

        AddressList = " "
        Group = "EmailTest"

        Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
        With olApp
            Set myNamespace = .GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
            Set myItem = myFolder.Items(Group)
            For I = 1 To myItem.MemberCount
                    AddressList = AddressList & myItem.GetMember(I).Address
        End With


        GetContactGroupAddresses = AddressList 

    End Function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Outlook contact groups using MAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423425/how-to-get-outlook-contact-groups-using-mapi)

Comment: I did not pay much attention to that piece of code because Contact Groups are not Distribution List Items, <DistListItem>, and folder.Items was throwing an error.

`foreach (var curr in folder.Items.OfType<DistListItem>())`

Since you brought it to my attention I dug a little deeper. I reluctantly followed VS suggested and added

`using System.Linq;` 

and that worked. It returns a little more than I need but I can easily filter out the extra data. Thank you very much!